# Request for expository articles on supersymmetric geometry.

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, superalgebra, supergeometry

Various kinds of supersymmetric QFTs are studied in the physics literature. A typical physics talk describes a Lie "superalgebra" by a huge list of operators (with many supercharges, internal rotations among supercharges and other Poincare group generators) and commutator relations.

I am wishing that we can start with Spec$(\mathbb{R}^{p|q})$ (with some equipped bilinear form perhaps) and study its automorphisms (and the Lie algebra of the automorphism group) to recover the Lie "superalgebra" of physicists.

Is there an exposition of these ideas in the literature?